# How can I convert an Arch Linux VDI as a fully bootable system on an external hard disk in Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, arch-linux, vdi

I run Linux Mint 17 Quiana 64 bit and an Arch Linux VM. My aim is to convert my Arch Linux VDI into a bootable external hard drive. I am using a laptop so I’ll be using a laptop external hard drive in a USB enclosure.

I read that I had first to convert the `.vdi` into a `.raw` and then use `dd` command. Unfortunately I failed because the commands are not working; unable to find the .vdi on my system.

Could anyone help me to do this?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the details of what you have tried. Telling us that something didn't work isn't useful if you don't tell us what it is. Add as much detail to your question as possible. You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/875278/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are several guides if you Google for it. [This Ubuntu guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system) will work.

As for the location of your VDI: start VirtualBox, and check the properties of your virtual machine and/or check the available media from the menu.

From [the help pages](http://en.helpdoc-online.com/virtualbox_4.1.2/source/ch10.html):

> Starting with version 4.0, by default, each virtual machine has one
>   directory on your host computer where all the files of that machine
>   are stored -- the XML settings file (with a .vbox file extension) and
>   its disk images.
>
> By default, this "machine folder" is placed in a common folder called
>   "VirtualBox VMs", which VirtualBox creates in the current system
>   user's home directory. The location of this home directory depends on
>   the conventions of the host operating system:
>
> On Windows, this is %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%; typically something like
>   C:\Documents and Settings\Username.
>
> On Mac OS X, this is /Users/
>   username.
>
> On Linux and Solaris, this is /home/username.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

Boot up your VM, making sure you can access it via ssh.  Create and format the desired
partitions on your USB device (eg. /boot, /, home, etc..).

```
mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt # root
mkdir /mnt/boot 
mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt/boot #boot
 #Repeat for whatever other partitions you have.


rsync -aAxv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*,"/run/*"} root@virtualmachine.domain.net /mnt
```

Then you'll just have to chroot into it and fix your bootloader.